# Identifying a Question or Thread in Communications With StackOverflow

Tags: discussion, questions

Is there a question ID number or reference number that can be used to reference a question or a thread in email communications with SO?

Thanks!

Comment: Psssst.....look at the URL

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sure, just click "share" under the question to get a link to that question, or simply copy the URL from the URL bar, as it includes a unique id for the question in the URL.

Comment: Thanks @Servy.  I've been on Elance all day so I was stuck on the "ID" path.  Long day = one track mind. :)